# Jmeter non-GUI -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.print_field_names=true not getting honoured

Tags: jmeter

I need to have headers in the jmeter csv output, i tried jmeter in non GUI mode to with -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.print_field_names=true (command : jmeter -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.print_field_names=true -n -t ....).
The result file is getting generated without headers.

Can someone help me how to get csv output file with headers in jmeter command line mode ?

Note: I am using Jmeter3.1

Comment: By default, `jmeter.save.saveservice.print_field_names=true` and checked the headers are saved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

-Gjmeter.save.saveservice.print_field_names=true is worked for me in master-slave mode.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

By default, `jmeter.save.saveservice.print_field_names=true` in JMeter 3.1 version and ealier versions too.

The headers are saved when ran the following command (Non-GUI mode):

```
jmeter.bat -n -t Scrept.jmx -l results.jtl
```

Comment: Hi Naveen, Yes i did observe that but this didnt work for me

Comment: could you please share the command that you ran, and part of the results file?

Comment: Running jmeter in master slave mode

Comment: jmeter.sh -n -X -Jclient.rmi.localport=<port> -j jmeter.log  -G global.properties -l test.jtl -t test.jmx

Comment: tried -J"jmeter.save.saveservice.timestamp_format=yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.SSS" it worked perfectly. But print_field_names didnt work

Comment: 2017/01/12 15:55:29.426|772|SignUp|200|One Time SetUp 1-1|true|1129|898|1|1|771|3e943d45997f|0|545
2017/01/12 15:55:30.276|189|SignIn|200|One Time SetUp 1-1|true|847|617|1|1|189|3e943d45997f|0|24
2017/01/12 15:55:30.471|160|CreateClient|200|One Time SetUp 1-1|true|643|837|1|1|160|3e943d45997f|0|0